# Issue with the Menus layout

Tags: css, asp.net, xml

I am creating menus using XML, ASP . Net and CSS | Issue is that - Menu's layout is not fixed they are just like "justified" alignment. My question is that menus should be kind of left aligned.
I am inserting the code of the XML file, CSS and ASP.Net code file.
**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Menus>
  <Menu Url="~/Home.aspx" Text="Home" Value="Home Page" />
  <Menu Url="javascript:;" Text="Services" Value="Services Page">
    <SubMenu Url ="~/Consulting.aspx" Text="Consulting" Value="Consulting Page"></SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Url ="~/Outsourcing.aspx" Text="Outsourcing" Value="Outsourcing Page"></SubMenu>
  </Menu>
  <Menu Url="~/About.aspx" Text="About" Value="About Us Page" />
  <Menu Url="~/Contact.aspx" Text="Contact" Value="Contact Us Page" />
</Menus>
```

**ASP CODE**
Here is the ASP code file (Master page file)

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
    <DataBindings>
        <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="Menu" TextField="Text" ValueField="Value"
            NavigateUrlField="Url" />
        <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SubMenu" TextField="Text" ValueField="Value"
            NavigateUrlField="Url" />
    </DataBindings>
    <LevelMenuItemStyles>
        <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="main_menu" />
        <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level_menu" />
    </LevelMenuItemStyles>
</asp:Menu>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Files/menus.xml" XPath="/Menus/Menu">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

**CSS file**

A simple CSS which I have used in the code is

```
.main_menu, .main_menu:hover
{
width: 100px;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
display: inline-block;
}
.main_menu:hover
{
background-color: #ccc;
}
.level_menu, .level_menu:hover
{
width: 110px;
background-color: #fff;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
.level_menu:hover
{
background-color: #ccc;
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Expected output:**
[image]

Comment: Can you add the rendered out HTML of the menu (view source)? Its kind of hard to tell what your problem is without looking at the actual HTML the asp control renders out. Also, you have them with a `width: 110px;`. Not sure what you want when you say _"menus should be kind of left aligned"_ ... can you give an example of what you expect it to look like?

Comment: *menus should be left aligned*... Why don't you use `text-align:left` instead of `text-align:center`?

Comment: @zgood question updated with expected output.

Comment: @Mordecai .. tried it

Comment: @VinyGoyal is the issue that you want less space between your menu items? The output and expected output are identical with the exception of the widths. If that is the problem, note that you have a fixed width set on your menu items. That is the issue.

Comment: @ArielleAdams these are the asp.net menu control - I see a little different in both menus  - in our menu when I inspect the element, these are showing in table, tbody, tr and td format and the expected menu that I taken from an example are showing in UL, LI format.

Comment: @VinyGoyal that cannot be inferred from the code snippets above. As shown by the confusion above, contributors need more information (such as the generated HTML) to answer questions efficiently.